# Select Box is not changing immediately after changing input in ElementUi Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-6, element-ui

I have made a CRUD based admin pannel with laravue. Now my problem is that whenever I am on the update page, I can't change the category immediately. I always have to make change in some other field to view the changed category. Its working fine on add card page when all the fields are empty.

This is the video of my issue
https://thisisntmyid.tumblr.com/post/189075383873/my-issue-with-elementui-and-laravue-and-vue

I've included the code for my list page as well as the add/update page.

Code for the listing page that will lead u to edit page

```
  <div class="app-container">
    <h1>My Cards</h1>
    <Pagination
      :total="totalCards"
      layout="total, prev, pager, next"
      :limit="10"
      :page.sync="currentPage"
      @pagination="loadNewPage"
    ></Pagination>
    <el-table v-loading="loadingCardsList" :data="cards" stripe style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column prop="name" sortable label="Product Name"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="description" label="Description" width="200px"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="price" label="Price"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="cardcategory" sortable label="Category"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Operations" width="300px">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <el-button size="mini" type="primary" @click="handleView(scope.$index, scope.row)">View</el-button>
          <el-button size="mini" @click="handleEdit(scope.$index, scope.row)">Edit</el-button>
          <el-button size="mini" type="danger" @click="handleDelete(scope.$index, scope.row)">Delete</el-button>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
    <el-dialog :visible.sync="viewCard" width="30%">
      <el-card class="box-card">
        <h1>{{currentViewedCard.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{currentViewedCard.description}}</p>
        <p>{{currentViewedCard.price}}</p>
        <el-tag>{{currentViewedCard.cardcategory}}</el-tag>
      </el-card>
    </el-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Resource from '@/api/resource';
import Pagination from '@/components/Pagination/index.vue';
const cardcategoryResource = new Resource('cardcategories');
const cardResource = new Resource('cards');

export default {
  name: 'Cards',
  components: {
    Pagination,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [],
      categories: [],
      currentPage: '',
      totalCards: '',
      loadingCardsList: true,
      currentViewedCard: '',
      viewCard: false,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getCardCategories();
    this.getCardList({ page: 1 });
  },
  methods: {
    async getCardList(query) {
      this.loadingCardsList = true;
      const data = await cardResource.list(query);
      this.cards = data.data;
      for (const card of this.cards) {
        card['cardcategory'] = this.getCategoryName(card.cardCategory_id);
      }
      console.log(this.cards);
      this.totalCards = data.total;
      this.loadingCardsList = false;
    },
    async getCardCategories() {
      this.categories = await cardcategoryResource.list({});
      console.log(this.categories);
    },
    loadNewPage(val) {
      this.getCardList({ page: val.page });
    },
    getCategoryName(id) {
      return this.categories[id - 1].name;
    },
    handleView(index, info) {
      this.viewCard = true;
      this.currentViewedCard = info;
    },
    handleEdit(index, info) {
      this.$router.push('/cards/edit/' + info.id);
    },
    closeDialog() {
      this.viewProduct = false;
      this.currentProductInfo = null;
    },
    handleDelete(index, info) {
      cardResource.destroy(info.id).then(response => {
        this.$message({
          message: 'Card Deleted Successfully',
          type: 'success',
          duration: 3000,
        });
        this.getCardList({ page: this.currentPage });
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

Code for the add/update page

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <el-form ref="form" :model="formData" label-width="120px">
      <el-form-item label="Name">
        <el-input v-model="formData.name"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Description">
        <el-input type="textarea" v-model="formData.description"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Price">
        <el-input v-model="formData.price"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Category">
        <!-- DO something here like binding category id to category name sort of meh... -->
        <el-select v-model="formData.cardcategory" placeholder="please select category">
          <el-option v-for="item in categories" :key="item" :label="item" :value="item"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="editable ? updateProduct() : createProduct()">Save</el-button>
        <el-button @click="editable ? populateFormData($route.params.id) : formDataReset()">Reset</el-button>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Resource from '@/api/resource';
const cardcategoryResource = new Resource('cardcategories');
const cardResource = new Resource('cards');

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        price: '',
        cardcategory: '',
      },
      categories: [],
      editable: '',
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getCategories();
    if (this.$route.params.id) {
      this.editable = true;
      this.populateFormData(this.$route.params.id);
    } else {
      this.editable = false;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getCategories() {
      this.categories = (await cardcategoryResource.list({})).map(
        cat => cat.name
      );
      console.log(this.categories);
    },
    formDataReset() {
      this.formData = {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        price: '',
        cardcategory: '',
      };
    },
    populateFormData(id) {
      cardResource.get(id).then(response => {
        this.formData = Object.assign({}, response);
        this.formData.price = this.formData.price.toString();
        this.formData.cardcategory = this.categories[
          this.formData.cardCategory_id - 1
        ];
        delete this.formData.cardCategory_id;
      });
    },
    filterFormData(formData) {
      const cardData = Object.assign({}, formData);
      cardData['cardCategory_id'] =
        this.categories.indexOf(cardData.cardcategory) + 1;
      delete cardData.cardcategory;
      return cardData;
    },
    createProduct() {
      const cardData = this.filterFormData(this.formData);
      cardResource
        .store(cardData)
        .then(response => {
          this.$message({
            message: 'New Card Added',
            type: 'success',
            duration: 3000,
          });
          this.formDataReset();
        })
        .catch(response => {
          alert(response);
        });
    },
    updateProduct() {
      const cardData = this.filterFormData(this.formData);
      cardResource.update(this.$route.params.id, cardData).then(response => {
        this.$message({
          message: 'Card Updated Successfully',
          type: 'success',
          duration: 3000,
        });
        this.populateFormData(this.$route.params.id);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**Update**
here is the git hub repo for my project
https://github.com/ThisIsntMyId/laravue-admin-pannel-demo

Comment: Can you provide the details of the data you edited in the video?

Comment: Details in terms of what ? I dont get it? Its just just how it looks

Comment: @sugars I have added my full source code above. Maybe that could help you.

Comment: hi, I copied a minimal code based on the code you provided, but I can't reproduce your problem. This is my jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/suguoyao/76qvw4f9/ and you can improve it